# compare two arrays for common Items and return another array with the common items

Tags: java, arrays, element, items

So the problem is I have two array and have to check them for common items.Usual stuff, very easy.But the tricky thing for me is that I have to return another array with the elements that have been found to be common.I cannot not use any Collections.Thanks in advance.This is my code so far!

```
public class checkArrayItems {
    static int[] array1 = { 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    static int[] array2 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        checkArrayItems obj = new checkArrayItems();
        System.out.println(obj.checkArr(array1, array2));

    }

    int[] checkArr(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
        int[] arr = new int[array1.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
                if (arr1[i] == arr2[j]) {
                    arr[i] = arr1[i];
                }

            }
        }
        return arr;

    }

}
```

Comment: Convert to a list and use retainAll: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29

Comment: @canillas `can not use any collections`

Comment: so use 2 loops, iterate and compare. Use Google... There are a lot of examples of this.

Comment: @canillas i am looking through Google,but there aren`t any examples with 3 arrays

Comment: @СимеонПецанов You can use a default value like `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to differentiate between the correct i.e. common values and default values generated from `Integer.MIN_VALUE` shown on answer section

Comment: Just for reference - this solution is correct, but it's suboptimal for sortable arrays (see answers below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a MIN or MAX default dummy value for the elements in your new array `arr` using `arr[i] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;`. In that way you will be able to differentiate between the real and dummy values. Like below:

```
int[] checkArr(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
        int[] arr = new int[array1.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            for (int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
                if (arr1[i] == arr2[j]) {
                    arr[i] = arr1[i];
                }

            }
        }
        return arr;

    }
```

***Output***

[4, 5, -2147483648, -2147483648, -2147483648]

***EDIT***

***Conclusion***
When you iterate over `arr` all the values other than `-2147483648` are common.

***EDIT 2***

To print the common values as mentioned on the comment below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
checkArrayItems obj = new checkArrayItems();
int[] arr = obj.checkArr(array1, array2);
        System.out.println("Common values are : ");
        for (int x : arr) {
            if (x != Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
                System.out.print(x+"\t");
            }
        }
}
```

**Suggestion:** Follow naming convention for class i.e. make `checkArrayItems` to `CheckArrayItems`.

Comment: How did you iterate over this array.No matter how I try I always have a hashCode returned?Sorry for the dumb question

Comment: You mean `arr` after you return from `checkArr` method? Those values are value returned by Integer.MIN_VALUE

Comment: the code is perfect, its just I have no idea how to print out the result you gave above.Sorry about this :)

Comment: @СимеонПецанов check now

Answer (score 3):

In case someone was wondering how the "chasing" algorithm mentioned by @user3438137 looks like:

```
int[] sorted1 = Arrays.copyOf(array1, array1.length);
Arrays.sort(sorted1);
int[] sorted2 = Arrays.copyOf(array2, array2.length);
Arrays.sort(sorted2);
int[] common = new int[Math.min(sorted1.length, sorted2.length)];
int numCommonElements = 0, firstIndex = 0; secondIndex = 0;
while (firstIndex < sorted1.length && secondIndex < sorted2.length) {
    if (sorted1[firstIndex] < sorted2[secondIndex]) firstIndex++;
    else if (sorted1[firstIndex] == sorted2[secondIndex]) {
        common[numCommonElements] = sorted1[firstIndex];
        numCommonElements++;
        firstIndex++;
        secondIndex++;
    }
    else secondIndex++;
}
// optionally trim the commonElements array to numCommonElements size
```

Comment: You're right, forgot that `Arrays.sort()` is in-place, corrected.

Comment: The `common` array is going to have a *maximum* size of `min(sorted1.length, sorted2.length)`. You're allocating too much memory.

Comment: @PiotrWilkin I think OP said not to use `Collection`. Although I'm not sure whether `Arrays` can be called `Collection` or not

Comment: `Arrays` is just a utility class containing functions for dealing with arrays. Collections are, by definition, things that inherit from `Collection`.

Comment: (please don't ask me to write a merge-sort function from scratch)

Answer (score 0):

I'm lazy to type the code, but here is the algorithm.
1. sort both array
2. iterate over array comparing items and increasing the indexes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Because that is faster (n log n) than a quadratic comparison (each with each).

Comment: @Eugene: no, this has nothing to do with binary search. 

If you use a naive algorithm, you have to compare each element of array A with each element of array B, making the algorithm quadratic. 

If you sort the arrays first, you can instead keep the current index from both arrays (starting from A) and use a "chasing" algorithm in which you increase the index of the array with the smaller current element until you get an element that is greater or equal than the current element on the other array (if the element is equal, you add it to the "common elements" array).

Comment: @Eugene: that latter algorithm is dominated by the sort complexity (O(max(n, m) log max(n, m))), since the "chasing" algorithm itself is linear with respect to the sum of both array sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Declare an index before the two for loops

```
int index = 0;
```

that will hold the current position of the arr array. Then:

```
arr[index++] = arr1[i];
```

And also, since you initialize arr with arr1.lenght your array will be filled with 0s at the end of the not colision.

Comment: For that he can use a default value like `Integer.MIN_VALUE` i.e. which are not common inside the first loop